# Fire change event which was added using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a page with the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.hiddenField.value=(this.checked?'Y':'N');">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="N">
```

Pretty straight forward. A checkbox places 'Y' or 'N' in a hidden input when it's clicked.

In a js script I'm adding a "change" event listener like so (I left out some x-browser stuff):

```
myHiddenElement.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    //do something
};
```

Since the hidden element is being changed programmatically, its `onchange` event does not fire. I thought adding `this.form.hiddenField.onchange();` to the `onclick` of the checkbox would do the trick, but it does not.

Since I'm using `element.addEventListener`, the `element.onchange` is undefined.

How can I fire the change event for events added using `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you could do:

```
input.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( "change" ) );
```

More simple way would be this:

```
function changeHandler(){
    // whatever
}
input.addEventListener( "change", changeHandler, false );
...
changeHandler.call( input );
```

This is assuming that you don't need the event object in the handler, and typically for onchange you don't.

Another alternative is, of course to use something like jQ... (well, you know that word :) )

Yet another solution is to give a `name` and `value` to the checkbox itself and get rid of the hidden input. Checkboxes have been handled without any Javascript for years.

Answer (score 0):

I think relying on the `onchange` of the hidden field is the less reliable option. The `onchange` event of hidden and text inputs is not as straightforward as you would think. (For instance, the `onchange` of a text field fires after the text field loses focus, not while you are typing [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPPHM/)) It would be better to rely on the `onclick` or `onchange` of the checkbox.

JS

```
function checkChange(cb) {
    if (cb.checked) {
        cb.form.hiddenField.value = "Y";
        //do checked stuff
    } else {
        cb.form.hiddenField.value = "N";
        //do unchecked stuff
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkChange(this)" />
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="N" />
```